# Двумерный массив c++

Tags: массивы, c++

В данный момент, храню данные вот так:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix(15,std::vector<int>(15));
        Matrix[0][1] = 1;
        Matrix[0][2] = 2;
        Matrix[0][3] = 3;
        Matrix[0][4] = 4;
        Matrix[0][5] = 5;
        Matrix[0][6] = 6;
        Matrix[0][7] = 7;
        Matrix[0][8] = 8;
        Matrix[0][9] = 9;
```

Как можно хранить\заполнять их корректно? Массив имеет 30 индексов, в каждом массив из 11 индексов, я новичок в c++, разъясните пожалуйста.

Comment: сформулируйте вопрос более четко

Comment: А чем вас циклы не устраивают?

Comment: Ранее двумерные массивы я не делал, заполняется он в цикле, я не знаю корректно ли так будет и безопасно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще вариант - развернуть двумерный массив в одномерный. Для индексации в этом случае нужно будет использовать простую формулу для перевода двумерного индекса в одномерный.

Такое решение, несмотря на некоторое неудобство представления, имеет ряд важных преимуществ по сравнению с вариантом с вложенными векторами:

- Меньший расход памяти.
- Быстрый доступ.
- Возможность работы с численными алгоритмами (например, БПФ).